# Model State Validation in Web API

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-middleware

I have a custom model validator to validate and return custom validation messages.

```
public void Validate(Object instance) {
                // Perfom validations and thow exceptions if any
                   throw new ValidationException();
               }
```

Now, I want to validate each coming request using my custom validator.
 Middleware and Fitlers have **httpcontext** object and I am supposed to read the request body, deserailize and then call my custom validator to perform validations.
 I have suppressed the default automatic http 400 response.

Is there any  proper way to call custom validator before each request to Web API?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When `[ApiController]` attribute is applied ,ASP.NET Core automatically handles model validation errors by returning a 400 Bad Request with ModelState as the response body :

[Automatic HTTP 400 responses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#automatic-http-400-responses)

To disable the automatic 400 behavior, set the `SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter` property to true :

```
services.AddControllers()
    .ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions(options => 
    {   
        options.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true;     
    });
```

Then you can create globally action filter to check the `ModelState.IsValid` and add your custom model validation ,something like  :

```
public class CustomModelValidate : ActionFilterAttribute {
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context) {
        if (!context.ModelState.IsValid) {
            context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(context.ModelState);
        }
    }
}
```

And register it globally to apply the filter to each request .