# How to get all errors of data annotation validation and override its JSON representation in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core

I would like to get all errors of the `Data Annotations` after the request comes in . E.g. `[Required]`.

I localized the strings yet. But now I want to change the JSON representation of the errors which looks in default like this:

```
"errors": {
    "FirstName": [
      "Please provide a valid First Name."
    ]
  }
```

I need to remove `FirstName`. But generally the whole JSON structure. 
Where can I override that representation? Is it even possible?

I tried it with an `ActionFilter` yet but that is too late. The response is given before the methods of the `ActionFilter` are executed.

**UPDATE**

Further problem specification:

It is a web api. The error is returned before any code in my controller is executed. I need to get all errors which the Data Annotations like `[Required]` produce and format them. At the moment it seems that the errors are returned directly when any Data Annotation constraint fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to get all errors from ModelState and fill into collection :

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
    var errors = new List<string>();
    foreach (var state in ModelState)
    {
        foreach (var error in state.Value.Errors)
        {
            errors.Add(error.ErrorMessage);
        }
    }

    var response = new { errors = errors };
}
```

And then return to client side using JsonResult :

```
return new JsonResult(response) { StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest };
```

**Update**

When `[ApiController]` attribute is applied ,ASP.NET Core automatically handles model validation errors by returning a 400 Bad Request with ModelState as the response body :

[Automatic HTTP 400 responses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#automatic-http-400-responses)

To disable the automatic 400 behavior, set the `SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter` property to true :

```
services.AddControllers()
    .ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions(options => 
    {   
        options.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true;     
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But that is what I tried yet. The problem is that when using Data Annotations that code you posted is not even executed because the response is given before. How can I manipulate the JSON structure of that response?

Comment: what do you mean by "The problem is that when using Data Annotations that code you posted is not even executed because the response is given before " do you enable client side validation ? if yes , the server side validation won't fire if any validation fails on client side .

Comment: It is a web api. The error is returned before any code in my controller is executed. I need to get all errors which the Data Annotations like `[Required]` produce and format them. At the moment it seems that the errors are returned directly when any Data Annotation constraint fails. Client side validation is not connected to the server.

Comment: Ok,  Check my reply [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60106393/5751404) to disable automatic 400 behavior, set the `SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter` property to true .

Comment: Thank you very much! Did not find a solution like this before.

Comment: if the reply helps , please consider accept as answer which may  help others who meet same problem

Comment: I will. Can you please edit your answer so other people can see the correct answer directly?

Comment: Sure . Done .:)